# InDesign: Have picture next to text, but keep it in the text flow

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-wrap

Ok, I hope the title is descriptive enough, as I have no idea how one does call what I am about to ask lol

Here's what I want:
[image: 2 paragraphs with one picture for each one]

I want a picture to be part of the textflow so that its position changes automatically depending on how much text comes above / below the picture. However the pictures are supposed to be next to the text, not above:
[image: example of what I do not want]

How would I go about that? Something with drop-caps maybe? I am rather clueless :(

Comment: No, rather something with [anchored objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could offset the images using `Object > Anchored Object > Options...`.

You'll want to set `Position` to `Custom` and just make the `reference point` top right corner. This alone should get you quite close, but you can also adjust `x` and `y` offsets to fine tune it.

Now before you go and change these settings separately for all the images, I'd urge you to look into `Window > Styles > Object styles`. In this panel you can create, apply and manage styles easily. Make a new object style and apply this style to all the images you want to adjust and then modify the `Anchored Object Options` to suit your needs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my example I had the images in their own rows, but you could also have them sit in the same line with the text. That way you wouldn't (necessarily) need to offset `y` at all  if you set it `relative to Cap height` + if that line of text flows into a new text frame, the image follows because it is in that same line and you don't have to play with keep options in the paragraph styles.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! Sooo many options :O